# timedelta unit error and No axis named Date for object type DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a dataframe which looks like below:

| ID | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210501 | 15:09:34 |
| 1 | 20210501 | 15:19:34 |
| 2 | 20210501 | 17:58:03 |
| 2 | 20210501 | 17:52:30 |
| 2 | 20210501 | 17:52:28 |

I need to get a new column say Duration which should give me the difference of time on a date grouped by ID. e.g.

| ID | Date | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210501 | 00:10:00 |
| 2 | 20210501 | 02:06:02 |

I converted Time to timedelta using below code however, it gives me

> "ValueError: unit must not be specified if the input contains a str"

Code to convert Time to timedelta type:

```
data['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['Creation Time'],unit='h')
```

Code to get expected dataframe is:

```
data['duration'] = data.sort_values('ID,'Date','Time').groupby(['ID','Date'])['Time'].diff()
```

Error:

> ValueError: No axis named Creation Date for object type DataFrame

Please let me know how can I solve this and where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need a datetime dtype column to calculate the durations, so make a datetime column:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str)+df['Time'], format="%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S")
```

Then we can sort by ID and datetime to calculate all durations for each ID/Date:

```
df['Duration'] = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Datetime']).groupby(['ID', 'Date'])['Datetime'].diff()
```

Now we simply need to groupby ID and Date and sum the durations:

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'Date']).sum().drop(columns=['Time'])

                   Duration
ID Date                    
1  20210501 0 days 00:10:00
2  20210501 0 days 00:05:35
```